# Javascript based interactive map application

Tags: javascript, maps

Greetings,
I'm looking for a quick way of slicing the map of a country by regions and when clicked on a specific region, showing some gui with the info of the region. I am looking for a quick framework, plugin or such to achieve this swiftly. I know it can easily be achieved using flash but I want to rely on javascript instead.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

have you had a look at [Seadragon](http://livelabs.com/seadragon-ajax/)? I know it will do the slicing and the zooming for you but you'd probably have to extend it by yourself to get an info window to pop up.

Answer (score 1):

You may have a look at http://www.openlayers.org

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked Web Maps Lite from CloudMade?
http://developers.cloudmade.com/projects/show/web-maps-lite

You may just add CM.Polygon for each region, and then processes onClick event.

Combine these two examples:
http://developers.cloudmade.com/projects/web-maps-lite/examples/info-window
http://developers.cloudmade.com/projects/web-maps-lite/examples/polylines-and-polygons